# Recursively reading any java Object and pulling out complex types into a hash map

Tags: java, parsing, reflection, object

I need to write a utility program which would accept a blank HashMap and any object as arguments and return the HashMap

```
public HashMap returnMap(HashMap map,Object parseThisObject){

//logic to strip all children, children of children...... and place it in HashMap
//return map

}
```

This object contains a lot of objects within it and those objects within has a lot of children and the lineage goes on.

My utility must be generic enough to recursively read through all children until it hits primitives in each object, place each of those objects in the hasp map and return it back.
This is something like the parent would be there in the map. but the individual children also would be there as sub sequent entries in the map.

I am new to java reflection and I went through some tutorials and examples on the net. Not very confident about how to proceed. I believe this is one of the frequent requirements experts and professionals over here might have faced.

Plese help me with a starting point on this. If there is any bean utilities open source available to do this? if so please let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
public void fillMap(HashMap<String, Object> map, Object bean) {
    try {
        BeanInfo info = Introspector.getBeanInfo(bean.getClass());
        PropertyDescriptor[] props = info.getPropertyDescriptors();
        for (int i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {
            Method reader = props[i].getReadMethod();
            if (reader != null && !props[i].getName().equals("class")) {
                Object invoke = reader.invoke(bean, new Object[] {});
                if (invoke != null) {
                    if (!reader.getReturnType().isPrimitive()) {
                        fillMap(map, invoke);
                    } else {
                        map.put(props[i].getName(), invoke);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

this of course puts all fields from all objects into one map. You might have to create a map for each recursion step if you want submaps for children. I can give you that code as well if you need it.

There is no return of a map, because the one that is passed to the method is filled.

Comment: I found out that my object isn't a ordinary java bean of beans but has some inner classes too. Please could you tell me how this can be done

Comment: With bean introspection you can only access getter and setter methods of a class, but it does not matter if its an inner class. If you want to read every method you would have to use reflection: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at [Apache Commons BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/). It already does a large chunk of what you need, and may even do the whole lot in one go.