# How to read a complex Map and Collection

Tags: java

Am facing issue while reading the Map which is of form `Map<String, Object>.` This **Object** can be String/PrimitiveWrapper/List/Map. If the Object is a Map then this Map can contain a List and this List can contain a Map, ..... and so on. This is of nth level. I need to iterate the Object and get the values. I tried different ways but no success. Happen to see the below post but couldnt get the desired output.

[Recursively reading any java Object and pulling out complex types into a hash map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441632/recursively-reading-any-java-object-and-pulling-out-complex-types-into-a-hash-map)

Can anyone please help me to get the desired output. I have enclosed a sample program and also show the sample output.

**A brief introduction about the first output:**
*Customers* is a key for Map-Eight, *Customer* is the key for Map-Seven. Map Seven contains an array Six, so key should be displayed as *Customer[index].* Six[0] is a Map fiveA whose key is *Addresses*. FiveA contains a Map-Four whose key is *Address*. Four contains a list-Three, so Four key should be displayed as *Address[index].* Three[0] is a Map-One with key as *AddressLine1* and its values is *House 1*.
  So final key and value is:
*Customers.Customer[0].Addresses.Address[0].AddressLine1 = House 1*

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class StructureReader {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    StructureReader reader = new StructureReader();
    Map<String, Object> firstData = reader.getFirstData();
    // After iterating the first data
    // Output should be
    // key = value
    // Customers.Customer[0].Addresses.Address[0].AddressLine1 = House 1
    // Customers.Customer[0].Addresses.Address[1].AddressLine2 = Street 1
    // Customers.Customer[1].Name.FirstName = Joe
    // Customers.Customer[1].Name.Surname = Bloggs


    Map<String, Object> secondData = reader.getSecondData();
    // After iterating the second data
    // Output should be
    // l2Map.l3List[0] = some_string
    // l2Map.l3List[1] = 123
    // l2Map.l3List[2] = 100.5
    // l2Map.l3List[3] =
    // l2Map.l3List[4] =
}

private Map getFirstData() {
    Map one = new HashMap();
    one.put("AddressLine1", "House 1");
    Map two = new HashMap();
    two.put("AddressLine2", "Street 1");

    List three = new ArrayList();
    three.add(one); // index 0
    three.add(two); // index 1

    Map four = new HashMap();
    four.put("Address", three);

    Map fiveA = new HashMap();
    fiveA.put("Addresses", four);

    Map fiveB = new HashMap();
    fiveB.put("FirstName", "Joe");
    fiveB.put("Surname", "Bloggs");

    Map fivec = new HashMap();
    fivec.put("Name", fiveB);

    List six = new ArrayList();
    six.add(fiveA); // index 0
    six.add(fivec); // index 1

    Map seven = new HashMap();
    seven.put("Customer", six);

    // Final HashMap i.e HashMap<String, Object>
    // Now the Object is seven
    Map eight = new HashMap();
    eight.put("Customers", seven);

    return eight;
}


private Map<String, Object> getSecondData() {
    Map<String, Object> inputMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    Map<String, List<Object>> level2Map = new HashMap<String, List<Object>>();
    List<Object> level3List = new ArrayList<Object>();
    String level4String = "some_string";
    Integer level4Integer = 123;
    Double level4Double = 100.5d;
    List<Object> level4List = new ArrayList<Object>();
    Map<String, Object> level4Map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    level3List.add(level4String);
    level3List.add(level4Integer);
    level3List.add(level4Double);
    level3List.add(level4List);
    level3List.add(level4Map);

    level2Map.put("l3List", level3List);

    inputMap.put("l2Map", level2Map);

    return inputMap;
}

}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Khan

Comment: Your design has a bad smell to it.  So fix the design rather than add more code to bad code.

Comment: I agree with you, but that's the way i get the data to my component. Right now am working through recursive program to generate the output. Partially am able to get the output. Please let me know where can I attach my code here to have a look by others.

Comment: Can we read the above structure by using binary tree transversal?

Answer (score 1):

The example you have stated above is referred to as primitive obsession. Have you tried to design your models as per your domain requirements and use them instead of using maps and lists directly (The domain models can contain lists or maps as data structures).

Comment: I dont have any domain model. Right now am developing a component for which I get the input data in the form Map<String, Object>. I need to extract the data from the Map and should separate it as shown with Key and Value. After this there is a mapping file which matches this Key. Later some processing...... First task is getting the values from the Map.

Answer (score 0):

```
As per your design, i implemented logic for itteration and the output came as per the design. Hopefully it will be helpful for you.






    package com.core.java;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class StructureReader
{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StructureReader reader = new StructureReader();
        Map<String, Object> firstData = reader.getFirstData();
        // After iterating the first data

        //For Eight map
        Iterator iterator = firstData.entrySet().iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext())
        {
            String output="";
           Map.Entry entry = (Entry) iterator.next();
           output=output+entry.getKey()+".";

            //for Seven Map
            Map seven=(Map) entry.getValue();
            Iterator iterator7 = seven.entrySet().iterator();
            while(iterator7.hasNext())
            {
               Map.Entry entry7 = (Entry) iterator7.next();
               output=output+entry7.getKey();
               String name=output;
              //for Six i'e List
               List six=(List) entry7.getValue();
              for(int i=0;i<six.size();i++)
              {
                  //for fiveA i'e map
                    Map fiveA=(Map) six.get(i);
                    Iterator iterator5A = fiveA.entrySet().iterator();
                    while(iterator5A.hasNext())
                    {
                       Map.Entry entry5A = (Entry) iterator5A.next();
                       if(i==0){
                           output=output+"["+i+"]."+entry5A.getKey()+".";
                       }
                       else{
                           name=name+"["+i+"]."+entry5A.getKey()+".";
                       }
                       String surname=name;  
                       Map four=(Map) entry5A.getValue();
                       Iterator iterator4 = four.entrySet().iterator();
                       while(iterator4.hasNext())
                       {
                        Map.Entry entry4 = (Entry) iterator4.next();
                        if(i==0){
                            output=output+entry4.getKey()+"";
                        }
                        else{
                            name=surname+entry4.getKey()+"";
                        }
                        String adderess=output;
                           if(i==0){
                            //for three i'e List
                               List three=(List) entry4.getValue();
                               for(int j=0;j<three.size();j++)
                               {
                                   Map onetwo=(Map) three.get(j);
                                   Iterator iterator12 = onetwo.entrySet().iterator();
                                    while(iterator12.hasNext())
                                    {
                                       Map.Entry entry12 = (Entry) iterator12.next();
                                       output=adderess+"["+j+"]."+entry12.getKey()+"";

                                       System.out.printf(output+ " = "+ entry12.getValue()+" %n");
                                    }
                               }
                           }else{
                            System.out.printf(name+ " = "+ entry4.getValue()+" %n");
                           }
                       }
                    }
              }
           }
        }
        Map<String, Object> secondData = reader.getSecondData();

        Iterator iteratMap = secondData.entrySet().iterator();
        while(iteratMap.hasNext())
        {
            String output="";
           Map.Entry entry = (Entry) iteratMap.next();
           output=output+entry.getKey()+".";

           Map Maplist=(Map) entry.getValue();

           Iterator iterator5A = Maplist.entrySet().iterator();
            while(iterator5A.hasNext())
            {
               Map.Entry entry5A = (Entry) iterator5A.next();
               output=output+entry5A.getKey()+"";
               List l=null;
               Map mp=null;
               List list=(List) entry5A.getValue();
               for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
                   if(list.get(i) instanceof List || list.get(i) instanceof Map){
                       if(list.get(i) instanceof List){
                           l=(List) list.get(i);
                       }else{
                           mp=(Map) list.get(i);
                       }
                       if(l.isEmpty() ||mp.isEmpty()){
                           System.out.printf(output+ "["+i+"] = %n");
                       }
                   }else{
                       System.out.printf(output+ "["+i+"] = "+ list.get(i)+" %n");
                   }

               }
            }
        }
    }


    private Map<String, Object> getSecondData() {
        Map<String, Object> inputMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        Map<String, List<Object>> level2Map = new HashMap<String, List<Object>>();
        List<Object> level3List = new ArrayList<Object>();
        String level4String = "some_string";
        Integer level4Integer = 123;
        Double level4Double = 100.5d;
        List<Object> level4List = new ArrayList<Object>();
        Map<String, Object> level4Map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        level3List.add(level4String);
        level3List.add(level4Integer);
        level3List.add(level4Double);
        level3List.add(level4List);
        level3List.add(level4Map);

        level2Map.put("l3List", level3List);

        inputMap.put("l2Map", level2Map);

        return inputMap;
    }

    private Map getFirstData() {
        Map one = new HashMap();
        one.put("AddressLine1", "House 1");
        Map two = new HashMap();
        two.put("AddressLine2", "Street 1");

        List three = new ArrayList();
        three.add(one); // index 0
        three.add(two); // index 1

        Map four = new HashMap();
        four.put("Address", three);

        Map fiveA = new HashMap();
        fiveA.put("Addresses", four);

        Map fiveB = new HashMap();
        fiveB.put("FirstName", "Joe");
        fiveB.put("Surname", "Bloggs");

        Map fivec = new HashMap();
        fivec.put("Name", fiveB);

        List six = new ArrayList();
        six.add(fiveA); // index 0
        six.add(fivec); // index 1

        Map seven = new HashMap();
        seven.put("Customer", six);

        // Final HashMap i.e HashMap<String, Object>
        // Now the Object is seven
        Map eight = new HashMap();
        eight.put("Customers", seven);

        return eight;
    }   

}
```